# Why does scp say "No such file"?

Tags: shell-script, filenames, quoting, scp, file-transfer

I have a bash script that uses `scp` to copy a file from my machine to another. The script keeps on exiting after I enter the SSH password with the error:

```
<filename>: No such file or directory
```

Yet, in the script, I check the file, and it is just fine. I did `set -o verbose`
 at the beginning and here's what I get at the end of the script:

```
scp /Volumes/FX4\ HDD/Users/matthewdavies/Downloads/NCIS.S11E01.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4 root@rpi.local:"/media/3TB/TV\ Shows/NCIS"
root@rpi.local's password:
/Volumes/FX4\ HDD/Users/matthewdavies/Downloads/NCIS.S11E01.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4: No such file or directory
```

So, I tried executing the `scp` command as outputted and it was fine; it copied. What's going wrong???

Comment: try with `scp /Volumes/FX4\ HDD/Users/matthewdavies/Downloads/NCIS.S11E01.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4 root@rpi.local:"/media/3TB/TV Shows/NCIS"`

Comment: What's the difference between that and what I pasted there? And it says "scp: ambiguous target" because it's missing a `\`, but I added that in, and it works just fine…

Comment: you don't have to escape the whitespace ` ` in double-quotes. actually, `I think it had to be scp /Volumes/FX4\ HDD/Users/matthewdavies/Downloads/NCIS.S11E01.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4 "root@rpi.local:/media/3TB/TV Shows/NCIS"` because the last part(destination) is counted as a whole argument.

Comment: Sorry…I meant it's missing a \ in the remote dir.

Comment: @thkang see my updated question…

Comment: try narrowing the problem down; e.g. can you do `cd /Volumes/FX4\ HDD/Users/matthewdavies/Downloads/; scp NCIS.S11E01.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4 root@rpi.local:/tmp`? can you do `scp /Volumes/FX4\ HDD/Users/matthewdavies/Downloads/NCIS.S11E01.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4 root@rpi.local:/tmp`?

Comment: @umläute Works fine…

Comment: @daviesgeek so does the target path (`/media/3TB/TV Shows/NCIS/`) exist on *rpi.local*?

Comment: Yep. It most certainly does…

Comment: Please copy-paste the line(s) from the script. There is probably some quoting or whitespace issue that `set -v` doesn't report unambiguously.

Comment: @Gilles `scp "$inputFile" "$user@$server:\"$2\""`

Comment: I think I see what the issue is, but I just wan't to make sure. Instead of doing `set -o verbose`, use `set -x` instead. The former isn't very good for debugging, because as you noticed, when you copy/pasted, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but when I try the command you have in your example I get the following:

```
$ scp /home/saml/projects/Cooks.com\ -\ Recipe\ -\ Coconut\ Chicken.mht \
       root@remotey:"/root/some spaced out file.mht"
scp: ambiguous target
```

This is because you're quoting the target path and it also includes backslashes which are escaping the spaces. However when the current shell peels off the double quote, it will also peel off the single backslash, leaving the target path as a bare string with spaces. You need to do one of the following to nest it further, so that the spaces are correctly escaped:

#### Examples

*method #1 - double quote, single quote*

```
$ scp /path/with\ spaces/file\ with\ spaces.txt \
       user@remotey:"'/home/user/some spaced out file.txt'"
```

*method #2 - single quote, double quote*

```
$ scp /path/with\ spaces/file\ with\ spaces.txt \
       user@remotey:'"/home/user/some spaced out file.txt"'
```

*method #3 - single quote, backslash*

```
$ scp /path/with\ spaces/file\ with\ spaces.txt \
       user@remotey:'/home/user/some\ spaced\ out\ file.txt'
```

*method #4 - double quote, backslash*

```
$ scp /path/with\ spaces/file\ with\ spaces.txt \
       user@remotey:"/home/user/some\ spaced\ out\ file.txt"
```

*method #5 - triple backslashes*

```
$ scp /path/with\ spaces/file\ with\ spaces.txt \
       user@remotey:/home/user/some\\\ spaced\\\ out\\\ file.txt
```

Comment: No, the destination is correct. `"foo\ bar"` is equivalent to `'foo\ bar'`, not `'foo bar'` — a backslash between double quotes is only erased if it's followed by `\"$`, backquote or newline.