# scp to remote Windows hosts with spaces in path: ambiguous target

Tags: windows, scp, escape-characters

I'm trying to scp a file from my local linux machine to a remote Windows machine, and I'm coming up with some inconsistencies in how scp handles Windows file paths with spaces...

This works, note that spaces are properly escaped in the path to the local file:

```
scp /home/will/file\ with\ spaces.txt remote@host:D:/Users/will/Downloads/
```

However, this does **not** work, despite the space in the "Google Drive" folder being properly escaped:

```
scp /home/will/file\ with\ spaces.txt remote@host:D:/Users/will/Google\\ Drive/Documents/Computer_Stuff/Home_Lab/folder
```

I've gone through a *ton* of resources online where people have similar problems, and all their solutions didn't work for me.

I tried putting the Windows file path in double quotes, single quotes, both with and without escaping spaces; I've tried using double `\\` and triple `\\\` to escape spaces; I even tried escaping the colon (`D\:`); and I tried explicitly stating a target filename and not. Nothing worked.

Then I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93254/why-does-scp-say-no-such-file/93259#93259), and **only method #2 works!** Why? What is the difference between surrounding the Windows file path in `'"`, and `"'`? Why can I simply escape spaces without using any quotes at all in the local Linux file path, but not in the remote Windows path?

Comment: Why don't you just single quote the paths? `'remote@host:D:/Users/will/Google Drive/Documents/...'`

Comment: since the remote host is a Windows Maschine i would try to use a Windows Style formatted/escaped Path like this D:\Users\will\Google^ Drive\Documents\Computer_Stuff\Home_Lab\folder

Comment: Windows has long been agnostic as to whether to use forward slashes or backslashes to delimit directories within paths.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the question and answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93259/250848), **method 2** was the solution that worked in my case.  Adding as an answer for convenience of later readers.

- Windows 10
- Git bash `scp`

**Single / Double Quotes:**
`scp ./myfile.txt user@host:'"/c:/AppName/a poorly named dir/sub_dir/myfile.txt"'`

Comment: OMFG!!!! Single-double-quote!!!! This magic just saved my sanity!

Answer (score 4):

I was going crazy on Windows 10 -- this worked for me

```
scp -r user@hostname:"/Library/Application' 'Support/Adobe/Common/Plug-ins/7.0/" ./Adobe
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-T` option:

```
scp -T user@remote.host:'"c:\path with\spaces in\it\foo.txt"' .
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shell is seeing `Google\\ Drive`, and parsing it as `Google`, followed by a literal backslash, a space (which separates the arguments to `scp`, followed by `Drive`, and then passing that on to SCP which doesn't know what to do now that you're sending it too many arguments.

To make this more clear, compare how the shell parses `Google\ Drive` and `Google\\ Drive`:

```
$ cat 443236.sh
#!/bin/bash
foo=(Google\ Drive)
echo "Unrolling \$foo[@]:"
for f in "${foo[@]}"; do
  echo "'$f'"
done
foo=(Google\\ Drive)
echo "Unrolling \$foo[@]:"
for f in "${foo[@]}"; do
  echo "'$f'"
done
$ ./443236.sh
Unrolling $foo[@]:
'Google Drive'
Unrolling $foo[@]:
'Google\'
'Drive'
```

Comment: Could someone advise the answer, e.g. what goes in an scp statement.

Comment: The two required arguments for an `scp` invocation are the source and destination for the file to be copied, e. g. `scp /path/to/some/file user@host:/location/for/the/file` or `scp user@host:relative/path/to/file ./directory/`.

Comment: That doesn't advise the solution to fixing the above issue -->" scp /home/will/file\ with\ spaces.txt remote@host:D:/Users/will/Google\\ Drive/Documents/Computer_Stuff/Home_Lab/folder"

Comment: That is already resolved in the actual answer.

Comment: An easier illustration of unrolling is `printf '<%s>\n' whatever`, e.g. `printf '<%s>\n' Google\ Drive; printf '<%s>\n' Google\\ Drive`

Answer (score 0):

Platform:

- scp on Ubuntu 18.04 ARM
- OpenSSH server on Windows 10

Single / Double Quotes in the above answer will work, but I want to use a directory variable. After some searches, the following works.

**If you want to use a variable in the script:**

`sshpass -p "$password" scp myfile.txt user@host:'"'"$directory"'"'`